# SQL Server transaction, where is uncommitted data held?

Tags: sql-server, memory-management, transactions

My question relates to how are transactions dealt with in SQL Server.

Lets say I have a user defined transaction that contains a lot of data, where does that data get stored during that process? Its only committed to the database file if the transaction is successful but where does it reside beforehand.

- Does that stay in memory of the program creating the transaction
- to the SQL server memory process
- is it written to the transaction log of the database?
- temporary files or some other disk location?

Answer (score 3):

Uncommitted data is written into the table(s) in question, it is simply not marked as committed until the transaction commits.  If the transaction is rolled back the data will be overwritten the next time a write occurs that needs the affected page.  Once the transaction commits, the data is in the table is committed and cannot be overwritten.  The log contains an ongoing record of what is happening in the database so that transactions can be rolled backwards or forwards after a system crash, or if a transaction is rolled back.

Comment: if it's written to the actual table, how are selects handled(before commit) that return existing data?

Comment: Row locks are placed on rows that have been written but not yet committed.  `WITH (NOLOCK)` can be used to see the uncommitted or partially committed rows from other sessions.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server uses [ARIES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_Recovery_and_Isolation_Exploiting_Semantics) write-ahead logging. Details are described in [How It Works: Bob Dorr's SQL Server I/O Presentation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2010/03/24/how-it-works-bob-dorr-s-sql-server-i-o-presentation.aspx). Write-ahead logging requires every change made tot he data to eb described by a log record so that crash recovery can reconstruct the database. To rollback a transaction all that one has to do is to walk the log backward and generate a compensating action for every record generated by the transaction. This will in effect undo everything done by the transaction. [Two phase locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_locking) will ensure that the compensating operation is always free to proceed.

See also [Inside the SQL Server Transaction Log](http://bradmcgehee.com/wp-content/uploads/presentations/Inside%20the%20SQL%20Server%20Transaction%20Log.pdf) and, of course, [ARIES: A Transaction Recovery Method Supporting Fine-Granularity Locking and Partial Rollbacks Using Write-Ahead Logging](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~brewer/cs262/Aries.pdf).