# What does ExecuteNonQuery() do during a bulk insert?

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, bulkinsert, executenonquery

I have some bulk insert vb.net code (working) that I have written. It calls ExecuteNonQuery() for each insert and then at the end does a commit().

My question is on where these inserts are placed, while waiting for the commit() command? I have not made any changes to support batching as yet. So with my existing code a million rows will be inserted before calling commit(). I ask this question obviously to know if I will run into memory issues, hence forcing me to makes changes to my code now.

Comment: The `ExecuteNonQuery()` will returns the number of rows affected. is it possible to include sample snippets, that you are currently using, then you will get much better answer?

Comment: They aren't placed anywhere.  They are executed.  You likely won't have memory issues, but the easiest way to find out is to do it.  How long is it taking you to write this 10 line program and run it to test it?

Comment: Here is a small blog post by some random internet person that I ran across while using google that you might want to read: https://www.jokecamp.com/blog/make-your-sqlite-bulk-inserts-very-fast-in-c/

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but these uncommited inserts are already in the table right? It's just in there waiting to be commited because when you select the table using `WITH (NO LOCK)`, you can see that the records are already there.

Comment: This may answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795259/sql-server-transaction-where-is-uncommitted-data-held

Comment: @un-lucky i know it returns the number of row affected. Im more interested in knowing if anything is stored in memory for each row, which means more rows more memory consumption.

Comment: This title of the question may cause confusion. Bulk insert has a specific meaning within SQL server, and is unrelated to ExecuteNonQuery.

Comment: @RobertMcKee the program is not 10 lines, its much bigger than that. I was interested in knowing if there was anything that is stored in memory for each row, which would mean i have to watch out for memory consumption. Does not seem like thats the case. Regarding your link, I actually followed that link about a month while doing research on bulk inserts. Thanks though, thats exactly the approach I am using.

Comment: @user1751825 yes I can afford to insert the data in one transaction. I am working on a `All or none` policy. If anything fails then the whole process is aborted.

Comment: @user1751825 regarding your link, yes thats what i was after.

Comment: @pnizzle Sorry, I didn't mean your entire program would be 10 lines, but the important code you needed to test was.  Actually if you use the same code in the link I provided, it's 9 lines if you don't count the lines he used for benchmarking the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the normal [rollback journal mode](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode), changes are simply written to the database. However, to allow [atomic commits](http://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html), the previous contents of all changed database pages are written to the rollback journal so that a rollback can restore the previous state.
(When you do so many inserts that new pages need to be allocated, there is no old state for those pages.)

In [WAL mode](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html), all changes are written to the write-ahead log.

In either case, nothing is actually written until the amount of data overflows the [page cache](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_cache_size) (which has a size of about 2 MB by default).

So the size of a transaction is not limited by memory, only by disk space.

Answer (score -3):

in bulk insert query, command.ExecuteNonQuery() returns no of rows effected by insert,update or delete statement.

In your case after each successful insert , it will return 1 as integer.
if you are not using a transaction query,Commit doesn't make any sense. If you're not explicitly using a transaction, changes are committed automatically.

Comment: Uhmm.. I think that's not the OP was asking?

Comment: Commit would error if transactions weren't being used, so presumably they are. The question is about where this uncommitted data is actually stored.

Comment: This is not what my question is about. I know what it returns.